# LetsEncrypt cert renewal script not working via docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a web site running SSL done using lets encrypt. I have written/used a script following this [guide](https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71) but the cert are not renewed automatically. Every 90 days I need to manually run the lets encrypt renewal command to get new certs for my website.

This is how my docker-compose looks like for nginx and certbot

```
nginx:
  build: nginx-image
  image: km-nginx
  volumes:
    - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  depends_on:
    - keycloak
    - km-app
  links:
    - keycloak
    - km-app
  environment:
    - PRODUCTION=true
  command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  


 certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew --webroot -w /var/www/certbot; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

Comment: [You can see my reference](https://github.com/williehao/nginx-certbot/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: Maybe a typo, never seen this construct:  wait $${!}

Answer (score 0):

You should add the [cerbot verbose option](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#certbot-command-line-options) to your `cerbot renew` command, in order to check what is going on.

[The guide](https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71#ca20) mentions:

> Edit the script to add in your domain(s) and your email address.
> If you’ve changed the directories of the shared Docker volumes, make sure you also adjust the `data_path` variable as well.

So check the [`init-letsencrypt.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wmnnd/nginx-certbot/master/init-letsencrypt.sh) and make sure that:

- the correct domain/email is set
- the `data_path="./data/certbot"` path is present on your host since this is what is mounted by the containers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, which was caused by some (dunno anymore which one) environment missing. Try adding the same command (that you use to manually renew the cert) to root's crontab and you should see (in syslog/messages) errors showing missing variables or variable content, most probaly some $PATH part or similar.

Most scheduling systems (like crontab) do NOT deliver the full env, but a reduced one as there will be no **login** shell.

My best guess is, that switching your entrypoint to `bash -lc ...` will do the trick.

I'm using crontab to renew it with entry:

`0,15 22 1 * *  bash -lc "certbot --dns-rfc2136-credentials=/etc/bind/zones/certbot_update_credentials -q renew"`